# Kotlin CustomView 2-way databinding

Tags: data-binding, kotlin, 2-way-object-databinding

I have 1 custom view that contains : TextView -> label ; EditText -> input ; TextView -> error message

I set the desired text on my EditText from my custom view using custom attribute

My binding adapter look like :

```
@InverseBindingMethods(InverseBindingMethod(type = CustImp::class,attribute = "customtext"))
class BindingAdapters {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("customtext")
        fun settextulmeui(editText: CustImp, text: String?) {
            text?.let {
                if (it != editText.nInput.text.toString()) {
                    editText.nInput.setText(it)
                }
            }
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter(value = ["customtextAttrChanged"], requireAll = false)
        fun setListener(editText: CustImp, listener: InverseBindingListener?) {
            if (listener != null) {
                editText.nInput.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                    override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

                    }

                    override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

                    }

                    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                        listener.onChange()
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "customtext")
        fun gettextulmeui(nMe: CustImp): String {
            return nMe.nInput.text.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

using in my layout like :

```
    <CustImp
        android:id="@+id/mTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:customtext="@={login.mytext}"
              />
```

Using my observablefield "mytext" i can pre-populate my edittext from my customview. I can get any new value that was typed if i hit a submit button ( get the new value using my observablefield in my view model )

But : if i rotate the screen i lose all data;

Any help/clue? 
Thanks

Comment: Where are you holding your content object called `login` in your layout? Is it extending `ViewModel`?

Comment: yes. Else the pre-populate value can not be displayed

Comment: Are you using `ViewModelProviders` to get models instance? If not it looks like your model creates every time `onCreate` calls.

Comment: can you please give me example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you say everything clears after rotating screen it seems you just creating your model object in `onCreate`.

```
model = ModelClass()
```

Instead you should use `ViewModelProviders` to get possibly existing instance.

```
protected fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    ...
    model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ModelClass::class.java);
    //"this" must be Activity reference
}
```

But for that your `ModelClass` must extend [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel) class and have empty constructor.

Of course, you can use [onSaveInstanceState method to save models state](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras), but for me `ViewModel` is better.

P.S. Saying "model" I mean object called `login` in your layout xml, that contains data for interface.